# Presenting a different storyboard upon launch

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7

I'd like to present a different storyboard scene to the user based on some conditions (if the user has previously logged in, show the welcome scene; if they're a new user, show the signup screen).

Whether the user has logged in previously will be stored in sqlite - but where should I check for this, and how can I load the default initial scene based on this?

I've looked at doing performSegue in the AppDelegate, but I don't think segue's are the right approach.

Any ideas how to go about this one? 
Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the app delegate's `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method.

First, you need to include the logic in here to determine which storyboard to load.  Once you've determined which storyboard to load, the storyboard can be loaded as such:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YOUR_STORYBOARD" 
    bundle:nil];

UIViewController *initialViewController = [storyBoard 
    instantiateInitialViewController];

[self.window setRootViewController:initialViewController];
```

Comment: Ah ok, so it's a completely different storyboard rather than scene.

Comment: Your question was asking how to present a different storyboard.

Comment: Heh, you're right - I should have clarified that I wasn't 100% sure that this is the usual (recommended) approach.

Answer (score -1):

Hey This is what you can do , remove the main interface file from the settings and then using the following code.

1. Step 1:
   Select the Project and then select General Settings.

[image]
2. Step 2

Use the below code with your conditions.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.window=[[UIWindow alloc] init];
    [self.window setFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];

     if(signedIn){
     //Create Account Storyboard
    UIStoryboard *board=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"A" bundle:nil];
     [self.window setRootViewController:[board instantiateInitialViewController]];
     }else{
      //Signup StoryBoard
    UIStoryboard *board=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"B" bundle:nil];
     [self.window setRootViewController:[board instantiateInitialViewController]];
    }

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```